# docker: bind mount host folder: how to manage dockerfiles for different host uid:gid

Tags: docker

On my host my `uid` and `gid` are:

```
$ id ravi
uid=1000(ravi) gid=100(users)
```

i want to mount a folder `host_test` with `uid:gid` = `1000:100` into docker

I have the following docker and its id

```
$ docker run --rm  -it python:3.7.9-buster /bin/bash
root@48d7d3122ffd:/# id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@48d7d3122ffd:/#
```

After going through various solutions, the best solution i see is to create a user and group same as host on docker image.

i.e

`Dockerfile_mypc`

```
FROM python:3.7.9-buster

RUN groupadd --gid 100 users \
  && useradd --uid 1000 --gid users --create-home ravi

WORKDIR /home/ravi

USER ravi
```

this now solves the problem of permissions

but when I want to use this `Dockerfie` on `aws ubuntu instance`, I see there the user `ubuntu` has `1000:1000` has `uid` and `gid`. So again i have to change the Dockerfile

`Dockerfile_aws`

```
FROM python:3.7.9-buster

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 users \
  && useradd --uid 1000 --gid users --create-home ubuntu

WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

USER ubuntu
```

I am just looking what is the best practise. Should i make Dockerfiles for each system where ever i am going to setup like

```
Dockerfile_mypc
Dockerfile_aws
```

or is there any way i can do this with single dockerfile

Because i have to mount the host folder from `my pc to docker` in `development` and also mount host folder from `aws ubuntu instance to docker` in `production`

Comment: Use Docker arguments (ARGs) in the Dockerfile so the UID and the GID can be configured during the build.

Comment: It seems like you're missing the Dockerfile lines that `COPY` your application code in?  Why does it matter if the container uid matches the host's uid?  (If it's important to you to manage the code and language runtime separately from building it into a Docker image, can you use a general-purpose automation tool like Chef, Ansible, or Salt Stack to install the appropriate language runtime on the target host?)

Comment: I am looking w.r.t development, if i use mounting host folder, my chages are reflected immediately inside docker